# on-screen keyboards' way of sending keys

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys, on-screen-keyboard

Some online games that have game guards like XIGNCODE3 disables the events sent by programs that send automatic key events to their games. But the microsoft's On-screen keyboard doesn't get blocked(also some on-screen keyboards sold in the internet). It is weird, because if you make a program using vb.net that uses sendKeys, it doesn't work.

My question is, is the way of sending keys by on-screen keyboards differ that the sendKeys in VB.net?

P.S: not making a bot or something(already made one and failed). Now i'm just curious, no more bot making :D promise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be able to do it using the [Windows Driver Kit](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-8-Driver-Samples-5e1aa62e). I'd especially look at the [Keyboard Input WDF Filter Driver (Kbfiltr)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Kbfiltr-WDF-Version-685ff5c4) sample.

If you wrote your own keyboard driver and installed on the machine, you could probably write your own VB.Net code to "drive" the keyboard as you want.

Comment: is this like making a real keyboard but as a software? is this how they make onscreen keyboards?

Comment: @Ceeee There might be some other way to do it, but this is where I'd start if I wanted to "fake" a hardware device. One of the related samples in the WDK, [Virtual serial driver sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Virtual-serial-driver-8383ea42), even includes a sample driver called `FakeModem`.

Comment: Thanks. my curiosity is fed. by the way, im preparing to study making a driver and i think ill start with a software-only driver which i found in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527707/writing-a-keyboard-device-driver. thank you very much