# Customize Additional Numeric Keyboard On Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, ms-word, keyboard, driver

I have to **write a software** (on Microsoft Windows) that, with a minimal user input, changes the inputs of a **numeric keyboard** (a **separate hardware**, different from the main keyboard) exchanging the original inputs with the **Microsoft Word shortcuts for equation sybols** (in the equation editor).

The software has to work with only **one specific numeric keyboard's model**, but I can't use the expensive programmable ones.

My knowledge of the Windows inner workings is near to zero, but i think that to do this i have mainly two options:

1. Use the **windows API**
2. **Write my own driver** for the specific keyboard

I have some concerns with both approaches. If i have to use the API, is it possible to change the keyboard mapping? If yes, How?

If i choose to write the driver instead, can i associate more than one ASCII character to a single key as required for my goal? How much hard is it for who has never wrote one?

Wich of the two options is the fastest to do? What model of numeric keyboard is most suited for the job?

Let me know also if there are other ways to achieve this i haven't thought of. Link to useful documentation will be very appreciated.

Comment: This is far too broad for here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan where I should write it then?

Comment: Don't know. Not here. Not in this form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527707/writing-a-keyboard-device-driver I thought that if this one was allowed mine would be too, if you have any suggestion to narrow it down, i'll appreciate.